# Is it safe to assign struct value by using pointer

Tags: c

I have the following struct:

```
struct foo
{
   int  a;
   char b;
};
```

It is stored to memory and pointer to it can be unaligned (odd address).

So, is this safe?:

```
const struct foo a = *((struct foo*)char_ptr);
```

I am worrying, because the integer member of the source struct can be in odd address. In some systems reading of (multi byte) integer from odd adderess causes problems.

**EDIT:**
 For avoiding off-topic commenting about usage of `const`, I did remove a `const` from the code. (I never cast const pointer to non-const pointer, even in this case where it should not cause any problems)

**And** more about context of problem:
This kind of structure is part of protocol frame. And it can be in any offset inside the frame. In the real code the struct have `__attribute__((packed))` attribute. But that probably not change the answer?

Anyway, I could use `memcopy` and non-const `a` for solving the problem. But I would like to use the assingment, because it seems to be more elegant way (if it is safe).

Comment: compiler should take care of it. If a variable can be accessed normally, it can be accessed through a pointer.

Comment: @User1 - I would go back to your text book and read up about the keyword `const`

Comment: ^^ Rightly pointed out... const on LHS will not allow a variable on the RHS.

Comment: @anishsane Don't understand what you mean. It's always allowed to initialize a const with a "variable" value. If this takes place in declaration (like noted above) it's all completely legal.

Comment: It will generate error (not even warning), if LHS is global const or static const. It's because the memory for that would go to read only memory & hence value should be defined at the compile time only. But for automatic variables, it would just work. You can even modify the values of these automatic const variables via pointer, using proper cast (e.g. cast const int* to int*). Whereas, if you try to do same for global const or static const, you will get seg-fault.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the `const` stuff from the question. It was not the point.

Comment: I would expect the packed attribute to change the behavior. Since the structure is packed, the compiler must expect that the members may be oddly aligned, and it should generate code to deal with that. I do not have explicit documentation for that, though.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil : Ok, good point. There is a int in the begin of struct. So it is aligned agaist the begin of the struct naturally, so compiler maybe not generate code for dealing the odd-aligment of it? Or does it?

Comment: Once you pack the struct, its size becomes five bytes (given a four-byte `int`), instead of eight. Then, if you have an array of them, the array elements are placed every five bytes. This means the compiler cannot assume a pointer to the struct is aligned to a multiple of four bytes, because, even if `a[0]` is aligned, `a[1]` is not. (However, if you had a packed struct containing a four-byte `int` and a two-byte `short`, could the compiler assume a pointer to such a struct is at least two-byte aligned? We need documentation about `packed` or other attributes.)

Comment: So __attribute__((packed)) may make it save. [Documentation of the attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not safe, unless you know the pointer has the alignment required for the structure.

Here are some ways to know the pointer has the necessary alignment:

- The pointer was originally a pointer to this structure type before it was converted to a pointer to char.
- The pointer is a result of a memory allocation routine (such as `malloc`) that guarantees the address returned is suitably allocated for any use (which `malloc` does guarantee).
- The pointer has been calculated from one of the above in a way that preserves the desired alignment.
- You convert the pointer to a `uintptr_t` and test its alignment, provided this is supported by your C implementation.
- Your C implementation (particularly the OS and processor) permits unaligned access to objects of the type in the structure.

If you do not know the pointer has the necessary alignment, then you should not access the structure through a converted pointer. Instead, you can define a new structure and use `memcpy` to copy from the pointer-to-char into the new structure.

Comment: Ok, So compiler makes struct assignment `struct foo a =` field by field? (and not copying byte by byte)

Comment: @User1: The compiler may implement the assignment in diverse ways. It might process each field in some situations or might copy the whole thing in some situations. However, even if the compiler chooses to copy the whole structure, without regard to individual elements, that does not mean it calls memcpy and does a byte-by-byte copy. If, according to the language rules, the structure should be four-byte aligned, the compiler could use four-byte load and store instructions to do the copy, even if the structure contains some elements that are different sizes.

Comment: That sounds clear. Your comment was exhaustive answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

See [Data structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding). On most systems, the structure will be aligned & internal member addresses will be aligned wrt their respective sizes, while malloc'ing itself.

If you manually create a memory pool & use some section within that to store your struct object, then compiler will not guarantee you alignment, but if you use malloc to create the struct object, it is generally compiler's headache, to give you aligned addresses, with padding if required between struct elements.

Comment: His specific question was about the source structure, meaning the potentially unaligned pointer char_ptr (which I'd assume was a char*).  This is a common problem when parsing binary data from a file or network.

Comment: ^^ Hence the disclaimer: "If you manually create a memory pool & use some section within that to store your struct object, then compiler will not guarantee you alignment"

Comment: I do not think that should be a disclaimer; I think it should be the main point. Cast a pointer-to-char to a pointer-to-struct is highly indicative of accessing a buffer or some other structure that has been laid out by some external requirements. It **may** be that this pointer-to-char is merely something that has been created through memory allocation and address manipulations but that has the necessary alignment, but the asker ought to be prominently cautioned about this.

Comment: He doesn't need to be cautioned, since that's exactly what he asks about. `pointer to it can be unaligned` is pretty much the main point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you get your data from a source where the pointer to the data isn't necessarily aligned, the only safe thing you can do is memcpy and hope that your complier isn't "smart" and pretends that the misaligned pointer is actually aligned and the memcpy can be optimized (there are several older versions of gcc that have this bug, requiring you to write a custom memcpy function that's not called memcpy). Depending on you architecture you can get away with improperly aligned access, but it will almost certainly be slower, sometimes even emulated through kernel traps.

A side anecdote: This is usually a problem in network stacks in operating systems where the odd size of the ethernet header makes the IP header unaligned and if the hardware doesn't have the ability to misalign the received packets (some DMA engines can only write data on 4 byte boundaries), this requires the whole headers (or the whole packet) to be copied once more in software.